# How can I add proxy options to HttpClient?

Tags: java, proxy, request, httpclient

I noticed that the proxy settings won't be picked with HttpClient when using

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 and -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

That's a problem on my server where there is a proxy, and running my code gives me back

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

So the following code gives me back the response of the URL when I run ot on my local machine, but not, when I run it on the server. As it doesn't pick up the ProxyURL and proxyPort from the classpath I am planning to retrieve them manually (I will read them out from the config file), but I am not sure where I should add these two values to the request object, exactly, once I have them?

```
public String sendPost(String url) {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        HttpResponse response = null;
        BufferedReader rd = null;

        response = client.execute(post);

        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(""+ex);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: how are you passing those values ? and how are you retrieving them ? Also what do you mean by *easy way to add the mentioned proxy manually* ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I updated the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: No, my question is how are you reading `http.proxyHost` values ? where is the code ?

Comment: Perhaps [this example](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java) will help.

Comment: That indeed helped! I copied the way the tutorial suggested, and it works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Andrew can you please set your comment to be answer? I would accept it. Thank you.